# Вывести пирамиду на Java, используя циклы

Tags: java, циклы, for

Пример вывода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                if (j >= i) {
                    System.out.print((j) + " ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" " + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представленный код печатает только одну половину треугольника/пирамиды *по возрастанию*, его следует переделать для печати *по убыванию* и добавить вложенный цикл для печати чисел от 0 до 9:

```java
    for (int i = 10; i-- > 0; ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i; j++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(j);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
            if (j < i) { 
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
      6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5
          4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
            3 2 1 0 1 2 3
              2 1 0 1 2
                1 0 1
                  0
```

Первый вложенный цикл для вывода пробелов можно заменить на `System.out.print("  ".repeat(9 - i));`

---

Вариант со Stream API:

```java
IntStream.iterate(9, i -> i >= 0, i -> i - 1) // цикл от 9 до 0 включительно
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, 2 * i + 1)
            .map(j -> Math.abs(j - i))   // цифры по убыванию и возрастанию
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)   // цифра в строку
            .collect(Collectors.joining( // склеить все "цифры"
                " ",                     // через пробел
                "  ".repeat(9 - i),      // префикс из 2 пробелов
                ""                       // суффикс (не нужен)
            ))
    )
    .forEach(System.out::println);       // вывод готовой строки
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример на C#, на java сами переведите =)

```
int padding = 0;
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
    var pad = padding;
    while(--pad >= 0) Console.Write(" ");
    
    var num = 10 - padding;
    while(--num > 0)  Console.Write(num);
    Console.Write(0);
    while(++num < 10-padding)  Console.Write(num);          
    padding++;
    
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Вывод

```
9876543210123456789 
 87654321012345678  
  765432101234567   
   6543210123456    
    54321012345     
     432101234      
      3210123       
       21012        
        101         
         0
```